# Set Resolution Automatically on Video File Load

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor

When I add a video file to the timeline in Blender's VSE, the **frame rate** will automatically adjust to match that of the video (usually). The **resolution** will not automatically adjust.

Is there a setting or a Blender add-on that will enable automatic resolution adaptation on video file load?

Currently, I have to check the resolution using [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) and change the setting manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked for this Auto-Dimensions-changer about same time that the time remapping occurred. IIRC the issue was knowing what the dimensions of the media was before importing it? Anyway the bottom line was that it couldn't be done at import, however there is a retrospective change you can make after setting a clip on the timeline.

Select the strip and go to the Strip menu > Set Render Size. This will alter the current scene's dimensions to match the source clip.

[image: change scene dimensions in VSE]

Comment: Very good! I'll link that function to a keyboard shortcut and that should save me a lot of time since I'll use this a lot.

Comment: Now is Movie Strip->Set Render Size